¿Por qué el siguiente bucle no funciona con la segunda condición?
Estoy creando una API usando hono dev y bun js. El asunto aquí es que el código funciona en su mayoría excepto por cierta parte. Para que puedan entender la función, trabaja de la siguiente manera:
Tengo una base de datos en la cual hay dos tablas, una de reabastecimiento y otra de consumo de inventario. La tabla de reabastecimiento contiene entradas de material a un almacén, por lo que puede haber varias del mismo material y misma planta; en estas debo establecer el balance de inventario que queda, y para eso está la tabla de consumo en la cual solo hay una entrada por planta y material, pero el punto es que se verían algo así las dos tablas:
Esta es la de reabastecimiento

Y la de consumo

El punto es que funciona dentro de lo que cabe hasta que qtyUnitEntry es mayor a balance, por lo que mi código debería actuar algo así como una cola la cual se centrará de la entrada más vieja a más nueva, así que debería, por así decirlo: si tenemos un balance menor al consumo de qtyUnitEntry, pues pasar al siguiente (digamos 2 entradas de balance de 5 cada una por lo que juntas hacen 10 y tenemos también un consumo de 8 por lo que se restarían 5 al primero y 3 al segundo, dejando al segundo con un balance final de 2). Baiamonte un sistema de inventario.
Y es aquí donde llegamos al problema el cual es que la función que acabo de describir no la hace.
import { Hono } from "hono";
import { RowDataPacket, ResultSetHeader } from 'mysql2';
import { connect } from '../db/connection';
import { Context } from "hono";


export const consumingProtocol = async (c: Context) => {
    const connection = await connect();
    //Se hace una busqueda de los registros de la tabla sapconsume donde la cantidad de consumo es negativa, osea que si haya consumo. 
    //Si esta en 0 no se hace nada
    const [consumeRows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM sapconsume where qtyUnitEntry < 0');

    //Se crean dos arreglos vacios para guardar los registros actualizados de las tablas sapconsume y sapreplenishment

    const updatedConsumeRows = [];
    const updatedRepRows = []
    
    //Se recorre cada uno de los registros de la tabla sapconsume que se encontraron
    for (const row of consumeRows as any[]) {
        //Se pone la cantidad de consumo en positivo
        row.qtyUnitEntry = Math.abs(row.qtyUnitEntry);
        //Se hace una busqueda de los registros de la tabla sapreplenishment donde el material y la planta sean iguales a los del registro de la tabla sapconsume
        //Se ordenan por fecha de publicacion del mas viejo al mas nuevo

        const [repRows] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM sapreplenishment WHERE material = ? AND plant = ? ORDER BY postingDate ASC', [row.material, row.plant]);
        
        //Se recorre cada uno de los registros de la tabla sapreplenishment que se encontraron en la busqueda
        for (const repRow of repRows as any[]) {
            //Mientras la cantidad de consumo sea mayor a 0
            while (row.qtyUnitEntry > 0){
                //Si el balance del repRow es mayor a la cantidad de consumo se resta la cantidad de consumo al balance del repRow y se pone la cantidad de consumo en 0
                if (repRow.balance > row.qtyUnitEntry){
                    repRow.balance -= row.qtyUnitEntry;
                    row.qtyUnitEntry = 0;
                }
                else{
                    // En cambio si la cantidad de consumo es mayor al balance del repRow se resta el balance del repRow a la cantidad de consumo y se pone el balance del repRow en 0
                    row.qtyUnitEntry -= repRow.balance;
                    repRow.balance = 0;
                    //Ademas se devuelve el valor a negativo para que se pueda seguir consumiendo
                    row.qtyUnitEntry = -Math.abs(row.qtyUnitEntry);
                }
            }updatedRepRows.push({ ...repRow });

        }updatedConsumeRows.push({ ...row });
        
    }
    // Cerrar la conexión
    await connection.end();

    // Devolver los datos actualizados en formato JSON
    return c.json({
        updatedConsumeRows,
        updatedRepRows
    });
}; 

Muy probablemente es un fallo en mi lógica con el while pero no puedo hacer que funcione ni siquiera poniéndole breaks al bucle para que simplemente se pase en caso del else.
A continuación muestro el resultado al llamar la función en la api: por lo que se ve funciona a medias, mientras que no suceda lo comentado.
He aquí el resultado.
{
"updatedConsumeRows": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "plant": 1133,
        "material": "51830",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "plant": 1222,
        "material": "51830",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "plant": 1111,
        "material": "1002",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 0
    }
],
"updatedRepRows": [
    {
        "materialDocument": 5021763900,
        "plant": 1133,
        "movementType": 632,
        "postingDate": "2020-07-24T07:00:00.000Z",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 1230,
        "balance": 1065,
        "material": "51830"
    },
    {
        "materialDocument": 4989626719,
        "plant": 1133,
        "movementType": 632,
        "postingDate": "2023-02-02T08:00:00.000Z",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 12,
        "balance": 12,
        "material": "51830"
    },
    {
        "materialDocument": 876871874,
        "plant": 1111,
        "movementType": 552,
        "postingDate": "2020-01-10T08:00:00.000Z",
        "qtyUnitEntry": 10,
        "balance": 2,
        "material": "1002"
    }
]

}

Actualización
Resulta que la entrada de reabastecimiento no coincidía con la entrada de consumo. Como condición para que la operación sea creada es que las dos entradas coincidan en "plant" y "material" por lo cual al ser una plant de 1222 y la otra 1122 no se iba a hacer la operación. He de decir que también hacía falta un break para el caso del else, si no el bucle se repetiría de manera infinita.
A continuación comparto el Código final. Aun pienso hacer varias modificaciones pero por ahora funciona perfectamente.
import { Hono } from "hono";
import { RowDataPacket, ResultSetHeader } from 'mysql2';
import { connect } from '../db/connection';
import { Context } from "hono";


export const consumingProtocol = async (c: Context) => {
    const connection = await connect();
    //Se hace una busqueda de los registros de la tabla sapconsume donde la cantidad de consumo es negativa, osea que si haya consumo. 
    //Si esta en 0 no se hace nada
    
    const [consumeRows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM sapconsume where qtyUnitEntry < 0');
   

    //Se crean dos arreglos vacios para guardar los registros actualizados de las tablas sapconsume y sapreplenishment

    const updatedConsumeRows = [];
    const updatedRepRows = []
    
    //Se recorre cada uno de los registros de la tabla sapconsume que se encontraron
    for (const row of consumeRows as any[]) {
        //Se pone la cantidad de consumo en positivo
        row.qtyUnitEntry = Math.abs(row.qtyUnitEntry);
        //Se hace una busqueda de los registros de la tabla sapreplenishment donde el material y la planta sean iguales a los del registro de la tabla sapconsume
        //Se ordenan por fecha de publicacion del mas viejo al mas nuevo

        const [repRows] = await connection.query<RowDataPacket[]>('SELECT * FROM sapreplenishment WHERE material = ? AND plant = ? ORDER BY postingDate ASC', [row.material, row.plant]);
        if (repRows.length == 0) {
            row.qtyUnitEntry = -Math.abs(row.qtyUnitEntry);
            return c.text("No hay registros en la tabla sapreplenishment con el material y la planta del registro de la tabla sapconsume");
        };
        //Se recorre cada uno de los registros de la tabla sapreplenishment que se encontraron en la busqueda
        for (const repRow of repRows as any[]) {
            //Mientras la cantidad de consumo sea mayor a 0
            while (row.qtyUnitEntry > 0){
                //Si el balance del repRow es mayor a la cantidad de consumo se resta la cantidad de consumo al balance del repRow y se pone la cantidad de consumo en 0
                if (repRow.balance >= row.qtyUnitEntry){
                    repRow.balance -= row.qtyUnitEntry;
                    row.qtyUnitEntry = 0;
                }
                else {
                    // En cambio si la cantidad de consumo es mayor al balance del repRow se resta el balance del repRow a la cantidad de consumo y se pone el balance del repRow en 0
                    row.qtyUnitEntry -= repRow.balance;
                    repRow.balance = 0;
                    break;
                }
                
            }updatedRepRows.push({ ...repRow });

        }updatedConsumeRows.push({ ...row });
        
    }
    // Cerrar la conexión
    await connection.end();

    // Devolver los datos actualizados en formato JSON
    return c.json({
        updatedConsumeRows,
        updatedRepRows
    });
}; 

Y así fue el resultado final:
{
    "updatedConsumeRows": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "plant": 1133,
            "material": "51830",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "plant": 1222,
            "material": "51830",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "plant": 1111,
            "material": "1002",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "plant": 1112,
            "material": "59012",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 0
        }
    ],
    "updatedRepRows": [
        {
            "materialDocument": 5021763900,
            "plant": 1133,
            "movementType": 632,
            "postingDate": "2020-07-24T07:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 1230,
            "balance": 1065,
            "material": "51830"
        },
        {
            "materialDocument": 4989626719,
            "plant": 1133,
            "movementType": 632,
            "postingDate": "2023-02-02T08:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 12,
            "balance": 12,
            "material": "51830"
        },
        {
            "materialDocument": 235326541,
            "plant": 1222,
            "movementType": 552,
            "postingDate": "2021-02-02T08:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 140,
            "balance": 0,
            "material": "51830"
        },
        {
            "materialDocument": 5478542342,
            "plant": 1222,
            "movementType": 552,
            "postingDate": "2022-02-02T08:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 20,
            "balance": 10,
            "material": "51830"
        },
        {
            "materialDocument": 876871874,
            "plant": 1111,
            "movementType": 552,
            "postingDate": "2020-01-10T08:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 10,
            "balance": 2,
            "material": "1002"
        },
        {
            "materialDocument": 325236232,
            "plant": 1112,
            "movementType": 552,
            "postingDate": "2021-01-02T08:00:00.000Z",
            "qtyUnitEntry": 6,
            "balance": 0,
            "material": "59012"
        }
    ]
}

